# Cant start tor browser

Tags: tor

I downloaded tor but can't start it. This is what I keep getting

```
~$ start-tor-browser
start-tor-browser: command not found
```

I did download it, but just can't open it.

Comment: can you tell us how did you install tor and what command did you try?

Comment: Installing a program is more involved than just downloading.  How have you installed it?  It looks like you haven't so you should perhaps edit your question to tell us where you downloaded it from and ask for guidance on how to install.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide much information but I suppose you downloaded the tor browser bundle. Now you have a *.tar.xz archive somewhere in you home directory. What you have to do is to extract the archive and start tor.

I will presume that you downloaded the archive to `~/Downloads` directory. First you have to change the directory to the place where you downloaded the bundle. You can do it by entering the following command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

and extract the bundle via the following command (pay attention to the actual file name)

```
tar xf tor-browser-linux64-3.6_en-US.tar.xz
```

After you've extracted the archive, a new directory will be available, in my case it was `~/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US`, you have to change the directory once again:

```
cd tor-browser_en-US
```

and now you will be able to start the browser via following command:

```
./start-tor-browser
```

Please be aware that you will have to adapt the previous commands depending on the location where you downloaded the tor browser bundle and what bundle you've actually downloaded.